# Javascript Extension/Plugin not working when page loads (Cannot read properties of null (reading 'playbackRate'))

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, html5-video, firefox-addon

I created a simple playback speed controller for Odysee.com.

On FireFox, once a video page has already loaded, then I click "reload" on about:debugging to reload the extension, the extension works exactly as intended.

However, the extension does not work when I simply click on a video and the page loads. The extension does not load properly.

On Chrome, it gives me the error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'playbackRate').

How do I fix this? Feel free to copy everything and test for youself.

Here's the **JavaScript code:**

```
const body = document.querySelector('body')
var placementDiv = document.querySelector('.content__wrapper')
var vid = document.querySelector('video')

const decreaseSpeedButton = document.createElement('button')
decreaseSpeedButton.id = 'decrease-speed-button'
decreaseSpeedButton.addEventListener('click', decreaseSpeed)
decreaseSpeedButton.innerHTML = '<<'

const increaseSpeedButton = document.createElement('button')
increaseSpeedButton.id = 'increase-speed-button'
increaseSpeedButton.addEventListener('click', increaseSpeed)
increaseSpeedButton.innerHTML = '>>'

const buttonRate = document.createElement('button')
buttonRate.id = 'button-rate'
buttonRate.addEventListener('click', resetSpeed)
buttonRate.innerHTML = vid.playbackRate.toFixed(2)

var buttonRow = document.createElement('div')
buttonRow.id = 'button-row'
buttonRow.appendChild(decreaseSpeedButton)
buttonRow.appendChild(buttonRate)
buttonRow.appendChild(increaseSpeedButton)

placementDiv.appendChild(buttonRow)


function decreaseSpeed() {
    vid.playbackRate -= 0.25;
}

function resetSpeed() {
    vid.playbackRate = 1;
}

function increaseSpeed() {
    vid.playbackRate += 0.25;
}


vid.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
    buttonRow.style.display = 'block';
});

buttonRow.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
    buttonRow.style.display = 'block';
});

vid.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    buttonRow.style.display = 'none';
});

body.addEventListener('click', function () {
    buttonRate.innerHTML = vid.playbackRate.toFixed(2);
});
```

**Manifest Code:**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Odysee Playback Speed Controller",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Change playback speed to any rate you want on Odysee.",
"icons": {
    "48": "icons/odysee-playback-speed-controller-48.png"
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "https://odysee.com/*",
            "http://odysee.com/*"
        ],
        "css": [
            "style.css"
        ],
        "js": [
            "odysee-playspeed.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
]
}
```

**CSS Code**

```
#decrease-speed-button {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: initial;
  border-color: initial;
  border-image: initial;
}

#decrease-speed-button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#increase-speed-button {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: initial;
  border-color: initial;
  border-image: initial;
}

#increase-speed-button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6);
}

#button-rate {
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: initial;
  border-color: initial;
  border-image: initial;
}

#button-row {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: It means the video didn't exist at the time your content script ran. Use MutationObserver to wait for the element and then add your UI.